# How to create a generic Object in a generic function using T?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, factory

Good morning,

### Problem

im using Typescript to create a angular application. I want to create a method which takes a type Argument and pass it to a factory to create a new instance using the cTor. That works well if i know the type, but not if i don't. For example this works (line 4):

```
list<T extends IMdmObject>(page = 1, pageSize = 50) {
    this.http.get<T[]>(this.uri).pipe(tap(
        _mdmObject => {
            let _ = _mdmObject.map(x => this.createInstance<MdmCountry>(MdmCountry, x));
            this.mdmStoreController.dispatch(this.ressource, _mdmObject, StoreAction.MERGE);
        }
    )).subscribe();
}

createInstance<T extends AbstractMdmStorable>(concrete: new(mdmObject: IMdmObject) => T, init: IMdmObject): T {
    return new concrete(init);
}
```

But it isn't working if i'm using T instead:

```
list<T extends IMdmObject>(page = 1, pageSize = 50) {
    this.http.get<T[]>(this.uri).pipe(tap(
        _mdmObject => {
            let _ = _mdmObject.map(x => this.createInstance<T>(T, x));
            this.mdmStoreController.dispatch(this.ressource, _mdmObject, StoreAction.MERGE);
        }
    )).subscribe();
}

createInstance<T extends AbstractMdmStorable>(concrete: new(mdmObject: IMdmObject) => T, init: IMdmObject): T {
    return new concrete(init);
}
```

I am Aware of the fact that Typescript transpiles the code to js and that T isnt available after that Process. But is there a way to create an generic instance which extends AbstractMdmStorable?

### Remarks

- AbstractMdmStorable implements IMdmObject
- MdmCountry extends AbstractMdmStorable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok to use `T` as a *type*, but you cannot use it as a *value*.  So you cannot pass `T` as a function argument here `this.createInstance<T>(T, x))`.

This can be solved with dependency injection.  What you want to do is pass the class (the class itself, not an instance of the class).  But rather than passing it as an argument of the `createInstance` function, I would recommend storing the class as an instance variable of the factory.  In the constructor of your factory, you pass in a class to make an instance of the factory for that object type.

I don't understand all of your types here, but it would look something like this:

```
class MyFactory<T extends IMdmObject> {

  constructor(private readonly concrete: new (mdmObject: IMdmObject) => T) {
  }

  list<T extends IMdmObject>(page = 1, pageSize = 50) {
    this.http.get<T[]>(this.uri).pipe(tap(
      _mdmObject => {
        let _ = _mdmObject.map(x => this.createInstance(x));
        this.mdmStoreController.dispatch(this.ressource, _mdmObject, StoreAction.MERGE);
      }
    )).subscribe();
  }

  createInstance(init: IMdmObject): T {
    return new this.concrete(init);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Linda, you saved my day. I'm totally new to generics in ts but i wrote something similar in c# a few weeks ago, so i was just presuming that it works equally in ts. After checking that Code again I found out that i was using reflection there to grab the cTor. Have a great day.